# In a ring $x^2= 0$ implies $x=0$. Then every idempotent is central.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a ring $x^2= 0$ implies $x=0$. Then every idempotent is central.

Comment: Is this a question, or do you just want to make a statement? If it is a question, please provide some more context, i.e. your thoughts on the problem and what you have tried before asking us.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** Compute $(re-ere)^2$ for $e,r\in R$, $e$ idempotent.